# How exactly is the batch size measured in KB in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am quite new to Kafka and I was wondering how the batch size is measured in KB for a producer. I couldn't wrap my head around that.

So, the question is how do we measure the batch size in KB? I mean each payload will be of different size, so how does the batch size work in that case? Does the producer check whether the next message exceeds the batch size to decide whether to send the batch to the broker? Is there an option for batching some number of messages instead?

The same question applies to consumer as well, if there's such option or configuration for consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are important two configs for `producer`...

- batch.size  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_batch.size
- linger.ms  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_linger.ms

Producers control that each batch does not exceed `batch.size` in bytes, and send the batch unconditionally when `linger.ms` is reached. However, the producer does not cut in the middle of a message.

There are also important two configs for `consumers`...

- `fetch.min.bytes`  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_fetch.min.bytes
- `fetch.max.wait.ms`  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_fetch.max.wait.ms

The broker waits unresponsively until `fetch.min.bytes`. However, when `fetch.max.wait.ms` is reached, it returns a response even if there is no message.

All above configs are not broker side configurations. You must set configs each producer or consumer.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about the batch size? Does the producer wait to see whether the next message exceed the batch size? So depending on that the producer decides whether to send the batch to the broker?

Comment: The batch size is calculated each partitions of a topic. There are many factors to decide sending or not such as `batch.size`, `linger.ms`, `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection`. Read this more https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_batch.size

Comment: Yes but that still doesn't answer my question. I am specifically asking about the mapping between the batch size and message count and how that's handled.

Comment: I think this may be the answer, https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/acd1f9c5631ed2aec2d6ab238e6b81c1a9eb47a2/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/record/MemoryRecordsBuilder.java#L809  . This is the source code of the kafka producer. It says NOT exceed the `batch.size`.

Comment: Oh so that means we just check whether there's enough room for another message just as I thought I think. Thank you so much, this answers my question!